# How to hide nginx version in elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running an app on the platform Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone) and wish to hide the nginx version from the HTTP headers.  I am not using Docker.  Other Stack Overflow answers have recommended adding this to my `.ebextensions`:

**00_nginx.conf:**

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    content: |
      http {
        server_tokens off;
        passenger_show_version_in_header off;
      }
```

However this does nothing.  Should I be putting the file in a different spot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Ruby 2.2 + Passenger Standalone 1.4.3 doesn't use (original) Nginx 1.6.2. It uses Passenger Standalone 1.4.3 server, which is modified version of Nginx 1.6.2.

So, if you want to modify the Nginx config, you must edit the Passenger Standalone config. The Passenger Standalone config is located at `$(passenger-config about resourcesdir)/templates/standalone/config.erb`.

You can use following `.ebextensions`:

**00-passenger.config**:

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/hide_passenger_version.sh" :
    mode: "000777"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      CONFIG_FILE=$(/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/passenger-config about resourcesdir)/templates/standalone/config.erb
      if ! grep -q "server_tokens off;" $CONFIG_FILE; then
        sed -i '/http {/a\
          server_tokens off;\
          passenger_show_version_in_header off;' $CONFIG_FILE
      fi

commands:
  00-hide-passenger-version:
    command: sh /home/ec2-user/hide_passenger_version.sh
    cwd: /home/ec2-user
```

The above config will check the Passanger config for `server_tokens off;`. If `server_tokens off;` isn't set, we add `server_tokens off;` and `passenger_show_version_in_header off;` just below (append) `http {`.

*Before*:

```
$ curl -I http://itmustbeasecret.elasticbeanstalk.com/hello

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2015 14:21:27 GMT
Server: nginx/1.6.2 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.59
Status: 200 OK
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.59
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Connection: keep-alive
```

*After*:

```
$ curl -I http://itmustbeasecret.elasticbeanstalk.com/hello

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2015 14:03:23 GMT
Server: nginx + Phusion Passenger
Status: 200 OK
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Connection: keep-alive
```

NOTE: The above config only affect if the Passenger is (re)-started. So, you need to **terminate** your current instance.

Comment: You can also force the Passenger to restart after you applied `.ebextensions/00-passenger.config` by creating another `.ebextentions` script.

Comment: Thank you, Edward. That worked perfectly first time.

Comment: @EdwardSamuel -- can you give an example of how to make this change take effect by creating another `.ebextensions` script (without having to terminate the instance) ?

Comment: You can create a brand new environment with the same config, so it will not affect your production env.